# Rolling friction of a swedish type omni wheel dependent on the direction of movement

Tags: wheeled-robot, dynamics

I'm trying to find, as well as derive, the equation for rolling friction of a swedish type omni wheel (not mecanum) that depends on the angle at which the wheel is oriented to the direction of movement. Like [this](https://vladpetrescu.files.wordpress.com/2017/10/asml_article.pdf) paper says, the friction increases more when the wheel is going sideways more. Could you help me with finding the dependency on the angle?